# Remove everything else after this mark?

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

Data

```
C. Induction anesthesia, muscle relaxant, anxiolytics, 1st line sleeping disorder (but short time in market).

\part{Theoretical Questions}
Lorem
```

Code

```
cat                                         \
     10.6.2015.tex                          \
                                            \
| sed 's#\part{Theoretical Questions}.*\n##' 

> 10.6.2015_quizlet.tex
```

which gives STOUD exactly the same data and empty *10.6.2015_quizlet.tex*. 
The problem probably here

```
| sed 's#\part{Theoretical Questions}.*\n##'
```

I want to include only things which are before the text `\part{Theoretical Questions}` so to have only the Head before that sentence. 
There must be better way to do this.

How can you include only the Head i.e. before the match?

Comment: I don't understand the question. To my understanding of what you're asking, the command you've posted does exactly that. Please post some sample input, the output you're getting, and the output that you want instead. And what does this have to do with Perl?

Comment: Is the sed failing to match because you need to escape the backslash?

Comment: @Gilles I posted data and updated command. I get no change in the data in running the command. What do you get?

Comment: To repeat: Please post some sample input, **the output you're getting, *and* the output that you want instead**.  And ***why is your question tagged* `/perl`**?

Comment: @G-Man I added the output: as STOUT the exactly the same data. In the file, nothing. Perl -tag because, I think Perl can be better way to go here.

Comment: OK, a ***BIG*** part of the problem is that, if the command line that has the `sed` command really doesn't end with ``\``, and the `> 10.6.2015_quizlet.tex` is on a separate line, then you're not redirecting the output from the `sed` command.  You're running the `sed` command with output "to the screen" (strictly speaking, to the shell's default standard output), and then you are creating an empty `10.6.2015_quizlet.tex` file by redirecting the output of ***a null command*** to it.

Comment: Ah, I hadn't spotted the problems. It helps to know what result you're getting, to find out what's wrong. Remove the `\n` (the newline isn't included in the matched text) and double the backslash before `part`: `sed 's#\\part{Theoretical Questions}.*##' `. And of course the redirection goes on the same line as the command, I'd assumed that was a formatting problem in your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n 'p; /Theoretical/q'
```

This will print until the regular expression matches for the first time then quit.